BranchCache works on Windows 10 VDIs but not on Windows Server 2022
I have configured Windows Branch Cache in hosted mode in my branch office.
In my main office I have a central fileserver with a branch cache enabled Fileshare.
In my branch office I have a hosted Cache Server to host the branch cache, 2 VDIs (windows 10) , 2 Citrix VDA servers (windows server 2022) and 2 Management Servers (Windows Server 2022).
After configuring the group policies I can see in performance monitor that branch cache works for Windows 10 VDIs but not for windows Servers 2022.
The Windows Servers and the Windows 10s are in the same Network/Subnet.
The only difference I did between them is that you manually need to install the branchcache feature on the Windows Servers.
Using “Get-BCStatus” on the Windows 10/ Windows Server 2022 gives the same “correct” result.
Windows 10 VDI:
[enter image description here][1]
Windows server 2022:
[enter image description here][2]
Configuration info:
Windows 10 Clients & Windows server 2022:
Firewall:
[enter image description here][3]
Policies:
[enter image description here][4]
Windows Server 2022 (VDA & MGMT):
Firewall:
[enter image description here][5]
Central server:
Policies:
[enter image description here][6]
Tests:
When testing branch cache using the 2 windows 10 VDIs the Performance counters update.
(first copy to second win10, then copy from second win10)
[enter image description here][7]
Second iteration:
[enter image description here][8]
Info can also be seen on the client performance counters:
[enter image description here][9]
The same tests with windows server 2022 does nothing, neither do any of the performance counters on the windows server itself give any information.
On the performance counters of the mgmt/vda servers there also no changes seen, neither on the hosted cache server.
[enter image description here][10]
